# ltrace doesn't work on some binaries

Tags: linux, debugging, ltrace

According to the man page, ltrace is supposed to intercept and record the dynamic library calls on any executed process, however it seems to not work properly on some binaries.

Here is the way to reproduce the problem while trying to trace strcpy.

I first see that ltrace is able to work on some binary (wget here):

```
# ltrace -e strcpy wget --help >/dev/null
strcpy(0x63cc23, "auth-no-challenge")            = 0x63cc23
strcpy(0x63cc38, "background")                   = 0x63cc38
[...]
strcpy(0x63cf26, "verbose")                      = 0x63cf26
strcpy(0x63cf31, "verbose")                      = 0x63cf31
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

Now the same code doesn't work on httpd:

```
# ltrace -e strcpy /usr/sbin/httpd -t >/dev/null
Syntax OK
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

No library call was traced, although we can confirm that strcpy is called using gdb:

```
# gdb --quiet --args /usr/sbin/httpd -t 
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b strcpy
Breakpoint 1 at 0x15d08
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/sbin/httpd -t
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaad1b000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, 0x00002aaaaca4d610 in strcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I'm performing this on Fedora 17. Is this a ltrace bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: My Linux man page has this in the BUGS section: `Option -f sometimes fails to trace some children.`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the expected permissions (`setuid` and friends) and a proper daemon configuration, `httpd` is forking itself soon after it starts, and the original process then exits (before `strcpy()` is ever called, it seems). `gdb` automatically follows the new process, and `ltrace` can follow it, but you have to tell it to by giving it some additional options, e.g. `ltrace -f`.

Comment: I tried with below but didn't succeed  <br/> `# ltrace -f -e strcpy /usr/sbin/httpd -t >/dev/null
Syntax OK
+++ exited (status 0) +++`

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps `strcpy` is either not used (they wrote their own version that's in the binary rather than relying on the one in the C library), or it's fully inlined (meaning no actual calls into the library) or something.

Comment: we can confirm that strcpy is called using gdb. See initial description

Comment: The reason why _ltrace_ can't trace httpd is because _ltrace_ does not support **PIE** executable.  `$ echo 'main(){alarm(42);}'| gcc -fPIE -pie -x c -;ltrace ./a.out
+++ exited (status 0) +++`  <br/> `$ echo 'main(){alarm(42);}'| gcc -x c -;ltrace ./a.out
(0, 0, 460544, -1, 0x1f25bc2)                                                  = 0x3290821160
__libc_start_main(0x4004c4, 1, 0x7fff0b523c38, 0x4004f0, 0x4004e0 <unfinished ...>
alarm(42)                                                                      = 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++`

Comment: @NikhilAR I don't think this is true anymore